# Merging XML files SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis

I have a set of XML files that I need to load into a database.  A third party sends in the XML files which all contain the same information split across 10 or more individual well formed files.  The XML contains child parent elements down to 4 levels.  I started off using the XML Source type and outputting each element type out to an individual file.  The XML source component adds in a unique identifier for each element so that the child parent relationships can be re-established later on.  However the problem I ran into is that the auto generated identifier for each element is only unique for each file so as I iterate through the files it repeats.

Anybody come across this problem before and how was it solved.  One option I was thinking about was to merge all the files into a single XML file, how would this happen in SSIS as I would need to remove the duplicate root elements.  Alternatively I could add in the filename as a extra column to make a compound primary key but this is messy.

Comment: is it only possible to auto-generate numeric identifiers? If it were possible to  use guids (`uniqueidentifiers` in sql server) then this problem would not arise

Comment: Are all of the relationships contained within each file? In other words; is it possible to have a parent and child in different files? If so; you simply do not have the information required to resolve the details properly. If not; either process each file individually or create a composite 'business key' in your data flow. The composite key could, for example, be a combination of the filename and unique identifier.

Comment: You could a text file manipulation script to: 1. Remove the opening and closing root elements from the file 2. combine the files 3. Add root elements back in.